# Hide some x axis labels, only keep 1 matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a plot with multiple curves, and they have the same x axis but somehow they are overlapping so the x axis is unreadable. I would like to only keep the x axis label for `df.boxplot` while hiding axis labels coming from `df_median.plot()`. Plots are done through pandas.

I tried something like this with the intention of hiding the x axis labels for `a` only

```
df.boxplot(column=['vals'], by='date', ax=axes[0], rot=45, showfliers=False, showmeans=True, whis=0)
axes[0].axhline(y=df.vals.mean(), color='r', linestyle='-')
a = df_median.plot(y='vals', ax=axes[0], label='7 day')
a.xaxis.set_visible(False)
```

However this just removed x axis labels all together.

Comment: `a` and `axes[0]` are the same.

Comment: Could you provide some reproducible test data for `df` and `df_median`? And add an image of how the plot looks like without calling `a.xaxis.set_visible(False)`?